# Can't used Stored Variables in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I use Selenium IDE to make some test.
When I store variable like this :

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>RandomProductRef</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
</tr>
```

I can't use it sometimes like this :

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ChildPlaceHolder2_txtSearch</td>
    <td>${RandomProductRef}</td>
</tr>
```

It type ${RandomProductRef} in the input...
I've used the same way for an auth form and its works

Someone know why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set variable name to the value input of Selenium IDE:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>RandomProductRef</td>
</tr>
```

Then

```
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${RandomProductRef}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

gives XXX

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could see that not working, is because your selector `#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ChildPlaceHolder2_txtSearch` might be invalid at the time of execution.

Make sure that that element is present at the time of executing your `type` action, and that should work.

Comment: you're saying it's not saving the variable?

Comment: Yes I think cause echo failed too

Answer (score 0):

You should change the first command to save the text "XXX" to the variable "RandomProductRef".

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>RandomProductRef</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ChildPlaceHolder2_txtSearch</td>
    <td>${RandomProductRef}</td>
</tr>
```